# 1 : Set visual focus of an text field | 2 : deal with the char offset (JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript, forms, input

First of all, I work with chrome, but it should work on firefox. not on IE.

I'm curently working on a pesonal project, so no ruch, the idea is to make a very simple js text editor for webpage, you can click any 'p' element in a page and a textfield(not area) will open containing the value of the clicked element. The cursor in the text field goes exactly where the user clicked in the text. He can also select a word or a sentence.

I've almost finish the dev part, had many troubleshooting, this forum, others and goolgle as helped me a lot but still I have two problems.

The first one would be that when you click the text the cursor goes to the right place in the text field, but the text field if contain longer string than width doesn't scroll to the right place.

The second one is when you select a part of the text in the 'p' element, the script add a pink background 'span' arround the selected text on mouse up, I also remove the last span on mouse down, so before the mouse up. But the startoffset and endoffset will start couting from the end of the span, not the begining of the 'p'

I don't know if you understand everything, I don't have the right vocabulary and I'm french...

Anyway, thanks !

CHECK IT THERE : http://jsfiddle.net/ilycode/KBnKc/4/

Comment: Could you make your exact question a little bit clearer? Do you have any code to share?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ilycode/KBnKc/4/ code is here.

Comment: origin of the idea, other project thebeatniks.org/reports/papers/20.php